# SQL query resource - an easier way?

Tags: mysql

I am looking for some ideas or help on how I could make my query a little less resource intensive but I am not sure if there is an easier way to do what I am doing.

I have a search stored procedure that takes in a large number of parameters to search the database for different products. The user can search for multiple makes and models etc in the same search.

The way I work the search is the parameters are all organised and the call of the stored procedure is produced and saved in the database this is then called and the store procedure is executed and the results returned.

An example:

Make Ids selected : 1 ,2 ,3 ,4
Model IDs selected : 2,3,4

Stored procedure call generated

```
Call my_store_prod ('1,2,3,4','2,3,4')
```

This is saved in the database with a random string   eg "wmF14ndfglq2p3yuMMM6cr" then this is used to call the stored procedure using `$_Get['search_id'`] [www.site.com?search=wmF14ndfglq2p3yuMMM6cr](http://www.site.com?search=wmF14ndfglq2p3yuMMM6cr)

In the stored procedure, I then create some temp tables:

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_manufacturer_id;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_manufacturer_id (manufacturer_id varchar(255));
/*MODEL_ID*/
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_model_id;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_model_id (model_id varchar(255));
```

Then use a function to split the string of ids '1,2,3,4' and insert into the temp tables:

```
CALL sp_split(@manufacturer_id,'tmp_manufacturer_id');
/*MODEL_ID*/
CALL sp_split(@model_id,'tmp_model_id') ;
```

Then in the where clause I have something like this:

```
CASE WHEN  @manufacturer_id = ''
THEN information_view.advert_id = information_view.advert_id
ELSE information_view.manufacturer_id IN (select * from tmp_manufacturer_id2)end
AND
CASE WHEN  @model_id = ''
THEN information_view.advert_id = information_view.advert_id
ELSE information_view.model_id IN (select * from tmp_model_id2)end
```

This all is working fine but one of my problems is I need to return 7 Random "Featured" Adverts with the same search results.

The only that I have thought of is to do a `UNION` with the same query only with a

```
order by rand()
LIMIT 7
```

I was wondering if there would be an easier way to get my 7 random adverts without having to duplicate the whole query?

Any pointers for be really useful.

```
Server version: 5.7.37-log - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: look for FIND_IN_SET  in a where clause

Comment: @nbk with the FIND_IN_SET would I still not have to still have to UNION with the Featured Adverts and one without?

Comment: i can't see ana union in your code, FIND _IN_SET would look in a column named id with FIND_IN_SET(ìd,'1,2,3,4') if such a number is to find in id. Like i said take a very good look at liknk any search engine finds

Comment: To be honest, I'm not really clear about what your requirement is but as a start, you can write a shorter `CASE` expression [like this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e007788740cfef8a727b0c675d9e96c8)